# Javascript Regex group multiple

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get all groups of a regex match?

```
var str = "adam peter james sylvester sarah";
var regex = /what should my regex be t capture all names that has the letter a in them/
var match = regex.exec( text );
console.log(match)
```

What I want here is each name that has the letter a in it... I want to be able to capture **several** names preferably at the same time.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I have reposted a reformulated question at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707360/javascript-regex-multiple-captures-again

Please see that to see what I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try my example on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/rCgqOLahWm)

```
var str = "adam peter james sylvester sarah";
var match = str.match(/[a-z]*a[a-z]*/gi)
console.log(match)
```

Comment: Ah, damn. You beat me to it. I was struggling to remember how to format `.match()`. Here's another valid syntax: `str.match(/[a-z]*a[a-z]*/gi)`

Comment: Sorry, but I have reposted a reformulated question at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707360/javascript-regex-multiple-captures-again

Answer (score 0):

Regex is probably overkill for this situation. I think it would be simpler to `.split()` and `.indexOf()` like so

```
var names = str.split(" ");
for ( var i=0; i < names.length; i++ ) {
    if ( names[i].indexOf("a") >= 0 ) console.log(names[i]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have reposted a reformulated question at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707360/javascript-regex-multiple-captures-again