# Javascript regex multiple captures again

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok, I think I need to repost my question that was originally:

[Javascript Regex group multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705844/javascript-regex-group-multiple/14706027#14706027)

with a full example. I have:

```
        var text = ""+ 
            "<html>                           " +
            "  <head>                         " +
            "  </head>                        " +
            "  <body>                         " +
            "    <g:alert content='alert'/>   " +
            "    <g:alert content='poop'/>    " +
            "  </body>                        " +
            "</html>";

        var regex = /<([a-zA-Z]*?):([a-zA-Z]*?)\s([\s\S]*?)>/m;
        var match = regex.exec( text );
        console.log(match)
```

**Output from console.log is:**

[image: Output from console.log]

The problem is that I am only getting the result for the first  ... 
not the other... what can I do to be able to capture and walk over all stuff that matched?

Comment: PS: do not use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: Do you have a better idea of doing what I am trying to do? That is get the tags of <g:alert .../> which can really look as <r:method ... or whatever ..

Comment: What _are_ you trying to do? what results do you need, exactly?

Comment: Instead of regex you should use DOM functions to achieve this.

Comment: Basically, using Regex are wrong for your intentions because you are dealing with nested structures, i.e. recursion. And regular expression is unable to do this. To explain this, You should first understand that a finite automaton (which is the data structure underlying a regular expression) does not have memory apart from the state it's in, and if you have arbitrarily deep nesting, you need an arbitrarily large automaton, which collides with the notion of a finite automaton.

Comment: That is ridiculous, I see some advises and no reason or explanation provided!!! Explain yourself, don't throw comments. Except previous

Comment: @Cerbrus ... I want to get the tags <g:alert attribute="value" /> but I am do not think I will end up with a valid HTML structure to use a DOM parser... I am trying to build a template engine ala JSP or GSP style... so regex is fine, since I am planning on providing a mechanism to precompile it all once only

Comment: [Do not use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572)

Comment: Funny post.. but it all depends on what I am trying to do .. nested structured is not really allowed in my case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`exec` returns only ONE result at a time and sets the pointer to the end of that match. Therefore, if you want to get ALL matches use a `while` loop:

```
while ((match = regex.exec( text )) != null)
{
    console.log(match);
}
```

To get all matches at one shot, use `text.match(regex)`, in which the regex has `g` (global flag) specified. The `g` flag will make `match` find all matches to the regex in the string and return all the matches in an array.

[edit]
and that's why my example HAD a g flag set!
[/eoe]

```
var text = ""+ 
           "<html>                           " +
           "  <head>                         " +
           "  </head>                        " +
           "  <body>                         " +
           "    <g:alert content='alert'/>   " +
           "    <g:alert content='poop'/>    " +
           "  </body>                        " +
           "</html>";

// Note the g flag
var regex = /<([a-zA-Z]*?):([a-zA-Z]*?)\s([\s\S]*?)>/gm;

var match = text.match( regex );
console.log(match);
```

SIMPLE TEST:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var text = ""+ 
           "<html>                           " +
           "  <head>                         " +
           "  </head>                        " +
           "  <body>                         " +
           "    <g:alert content='alert'/>   " +
           "    <g:alert content='poop'/>    " +
           "  </body>                        " +
           "</html>";

// Note the g flag
var regex = /<([a-zA-Z]*?):([a-zA-Z]*?)\s([\s\S]*?)>/gi;

var n = text.match( regex );
alert(n);
}
</script>
```

working perfectly...

Comment: Sounds promising but unfortunately didn't work. I have edited your answer to give you a full example of what I tried...

Comment: @Hamidam: Of course it fails (goes into inf loop), since the text is matched again and again, and it will always return the first item. You don't understand how `match` is different from `exec`.

Comment: @nhahtdh you are right.. they are different... it appears as if I need the g instead of the m... I will post a final solution soon..

Comment: @Hamidam: I edited his post. `exec` and `match` are different. `String.match` will forget everything the next time you call it. `Regex.exec` will remember the position of last match and will continue from there.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks. Some of us uses firebug to run javascript immediatly rather than create a new page ;) 

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ee819093.image001(en-us,MSDN.10).png

Comment: no need to create a new page, just copy and paste the code to any online javascript test engine like jsfiddler or the one from w3school: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_match_regexp2

Answer (score 2):

This is what works:

```
           var text = ""+
            "<html>                           " +
            "  <head>                         " +
            "  </head>                        " +
            "  <body>                         " +
            "    <g:alert content='alert'/>   " +
            "    <g:alert content='poop'/>    " +
            "  </body>                        " +
            "</html>";

        var regex = /<([a-zA-Z]*?):([a-zA-Z]*?)\s([\s\S]*?)>/g;
        var match = null;
        while ( (match = regex.exec( text )) != null  )
            console.log(match)
```

Notice the **/g** which seems to be neccessary

Comment: @Adriano, don't censur. I think I am allowed to express myself

Comment: I guess i'ts more appropriate to post one (or two, three...) long comments to reply to a discussion. People in the future who will have the same problem will find your answer (clean and concise) and if they'll think it's good they'll upvote.