# Regular expression that matches group as many times as it can find

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I have written a regular expression to match some tags that look like this:

```
@("hello, world" bold italic font-size="15")
```

I want the regular expression to match these strings: `['hello, world', 'bold', 'italic', 'font-size="15"']`.

However, only these strings are matched: `['hello, world', 'font-size="15"']`.

Other examples:

1. (success)`@("test") -> ["test"]`
2. (success)`@("test" bold) -> ["test", "bold"]`
3. (fail)`@("test" bold size="15") -> ["test", "bold", 'size="15"']`

I have tried using this regular expression:

```
\@\(\s*"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"(?:\s+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+(?:\="(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*")?)*)\s*\)
```

A broken down version:

```
\@\(
  \s*
  "((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"
  (?:
    \s+
    (
      [A-Za-z0-9-_]+
      (?:
        \=
        "(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"
      )?
    )
  )*
  \s*
\)
```

The regular expression is trying to

1. match beginning of the sequence (`$(`),
2. match a string with escaped characters,
3. match some (>= 1) blanks,
4. (optional, grouped with (5)) match a `=` sign,
5. (optional, grouped with (4)) match a string with escaped characters,
6. repeat (3) - (5)
7. match end of the sequence (`)`)

However, this regular expression only matches `"hello, world"` and `font-size="15"`. How can I make it also match `bold` and `italic`, i.e. to match the group `([A-Za-z0-9-_]+(?:\="(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*")?)` multiple times?

Expected result: `['"hello, world"', 'bold', 'italic', 'font-size="15']`

P.S. using JavaScript native regular expression

Comment: Is the string a standalone one or are you trying to match it inside a larger text?

Comment: Inside a larger text, actually a markdown. The group is matched using the `String.match` function and then each case is handled with another function.

Comment: Could you provide some more examples of things you want to match/not match? The regex you're written looks incredibly complicated for what should hopefully be a simple task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript regex multiple captures again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707360/javascript-regex-multiple-captures-again)

Comment: @KubaWyrostek no, I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @TomLord let me edit it...

Comment: @TomLord It is not an easy task to parse code/markdown, especially with a regex. Actually, I do not think it is really a good idea to do it with a regex. Ok, if a regex should be used, then there should be 2 steps: 1) extracting with [`@\((?:\s*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[\w-]+(?:="?[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"?)?))+\s*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/yH4wA0/1), 2) tokenizing the match with [`(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|[\w-]+(?:="?[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"?)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/yH4wA0/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution is right, and actually this is (originally) a simple regex but a escaped string match is embed inside. Anyway, this is not a duplicate, given the correct solution you provided... also, can you answer this question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a 2-step solution:

- Extracting the substrings with [`@\((?:\s*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[\w-]+(?:="?[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"?)?))+\s*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/yH4wA0/1),
- Tokenizing the match with [`(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|[\w-]+(?:="?[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"?)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/yH4wA0/2).

Example code:

```js
var re = /@\((?:\s*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[\w-]+(?:="?[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"?)?))+\s*\)/g; 
var re2 = /(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|[\w-]+(?:="?[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"?)?)/g;
var str = 'Text here @("hello, world" bold italic font-size="15") and here\nText there @("Welcome home" italic font-size="2345") and there';
var res = [];

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    tmp = [];
    while((n = re2.exec(m[0])) !== null) {
      if (n[1]) {
        tmp.push(n[1]);
      } else {
        tmp.push(n[0]);
      }
    }
    res.push(tmp);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks so much, and thanks about the tips about using `RegExp.exec` - however, I'm using `String.replace` with callback and it works well! Thanks for your effort in debugging this long RegExp!

Comment: Just FYI: I unrolled the `"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"` with `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` for better performance. I will perhaps add more details once I have more time.

Comment: Thanks for that and this is just for my own small project - I'm trying to make a fill-in-the-blank generator (markdown -> pdf), so performance won't be a very important factor - although yes, regex performance can be very bad sometimes :) Thanks